# Navigation Component : How to pass safe args from main fragment to navigation drawer in Main Activity which hosts the main fragment?

Tags: kotlin, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-navigation, android-safe-args

I want to get safe args from the main fragment in the main activity, to provide them to the navigation drawer.
How can I get arguments in NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener, from an API called in the main fragment or any other fragment.

[image]